# setTimeout does not work as expected on IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, asynchronous

I have the following web page:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Wait until closed</h1>
<script>

function wait(popup){
      if (!popup.closed){
        setTimeout(wait,1000,popup);
      } else {
        alert('closed');
      } 
    }

var popup = window.open("http://www.google.com", '', 'directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes, width=1000 , height=800, top=' + screen.top + ', left=' + screen.left);

wait(popup); 

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open it with Chrome or Firefox, I see the message 'closed' after I close the popup. In IE11 however nothing happens. What is the explanation of this difference in behaviour? (i.e. which part of the standards IE11 does not adhere to, or interpret differently in this case, if at all?)

**EDIT:** reading the suggested answers, I tried to change  `setTimeout(wait,1000,popup)` to `setTimeout(function() {wait(popup);},1000)`, like this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Wait until closed</h1>
<script>

function wait(popup){
      if (!popup.closed){
        setTimeout( function() {
            wait(popup);
        }, 1000 );
      } else {
        alert('closed');
      } 
    }

var popup = window.open("http://www.google.com", '', 'directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes, width=1000 , height=800, top=' + screen.top + ', left=' + screen.left);

wait(popup); 

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

but this does not work either.

**EDIT:** The comments indicate that this is a duplicate, but since trying to change the code according to the suggested answers did not work for me until now, I modify the question by asking to change the above code so that it works in IE11 (hope that this is allowed by SO rules). The code shown does not work.

Comment: I am so confused, is this already solved now?

Comment: @Huangism no, I tried to follow the suggestions and for now these are not working for me.

Comment: @user7408846 your EDIT section indicates this works in IE11 now, is this not the case?

Comment: @Huangism I changed the question ending, I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: @user7408846 I don't have IE11 on my machine but I suggest you step thru and see exactly what is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one was kind of bugging me, so I tried it in on a local file and got the same behavior.  window.open returning null in both IE and Edge.  Apparently if protected mode is enabled, window.open will return null in both IE and Edge.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb250462.aspx

I'm not sure how to work around it.  Maybe a closeable frame?